# Could not reference properly d3js (4.7) from TypeScript (2.4.2)

Tags: typescript, d3.js, powerbi

I am starting to develop my own custom visualization for **Power BI**. To do this I have prepared my **development** environment but I require to use **D3js** javascript framework from TypeScript. I already installed **D3js** in my environment using **npm** and typings but I could not reference correctly to use it from my TypeScript code.

D3js is installed using typings so D3js is installed as a typescript type. The `index.d.ts` file (from D3) contains a ts module declaration where the module is exported as a namespace, here start the problem, the namespace declaration is marked as incorrect with the following message

### Global module exports may only appear at top level

This is the actual code from index.d.ts file (from d3js)

```
    // Generated by typings
    // Source: 

    module 'd3' {
    // Type definitions for D3JS d3 standard bundle 4.7
    // Project: https://github.com/d3/d3
    // Definitions by: Tom Wanzek <https://github.com/tomwanzek>, Alex Ford <https://github.com/gustavderdrache>, Boris Yankov <https://github.com/borisyankov>
    // Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

    export as namespace d3; //this is the line marked as incorrect

    export * from 'd3-array';
    export * from 'd3-axis';
    export * from 'd3-brush';
    export * from 'd3-chord';
    export * from 'd3-collection';
    export * from 'd3-color';
    export * from 'd3-dispatch';
    export * from 'd3-drag';
    export * from 'd3-dsv';
    export * from 'd3-ease';
    export * from 'd3-force';
    export * from 'd3-format';
    export * from 'd3-geo';
    export * from 'd3-hierarchy';
    export * from 'd3-interpolate';
    export * from 'd3-path';
    export * from 'd3-polygon';
    export * from 'd3-quadtree';
    export * from 'd3-queue';
    export * from 'd3-random';
    export * from 'd3-request';
    export * from 'd3-scale';
    export * from 'd3-selection';
    export * from 'd3-shape';
    export * from 'd3-time';
    export * from 'd3-time-format';
    export * from 'd3-timer';
    export * from 'd3-transition';
    export * from 'd3-voronoi';
    export * from 'd3-zoom';
}
```

}

Finally, I know that TypeScript has suffer a big change on version **1.5**, <**1.5** there were not namespaces but **external modules** maybe the **D3js** code is not tuned with the latest changes no TypeScript

How can I define a namespace from a module? 
Do I need to change the module for other object?

Answer (score 1):

I've just found the solution. As I mentioned, since TypeScript 2.0 a lot of things has been changed against previous versions so we need a different way to install d3js

Instead of using typings (typings install --save dt~d3) we should the brand new @types this way:

```
npm install @types/d3
```

If you need a specific version that was my case in order to develop PBI custom visualizations from current source code you can include it this way: (to get version 3.5.34)

```
npm install @types/d3@3.5.34
```